# Akka BufferOverflowException when send many singleRequest

Tags: java, scala, akka, future, akka-http

Here's my code

```
Future.sequence((2 to firstPage.pages).map
{ count =>
    getCommentPage(av, count)
}).map(//do something)
```

In `getCommentPage`, one `Http().singleRequest` is used to get data, like this:

```
val responseFuture: Future[HttpResponse] =
    Http(system).singleRequest(HttpRequest(GET, uri = requestUri))
responseFuture
    .map(_.entity)
    .flatMap(_.toStrict(10 seconds)(materializer))
    .map(_.data)
    .map(_.utf8String)
    .map((jsonString: String) => {
        //do something to extract data
    }
```

Small `firstPage.pages` will work well, but when `firstPage.pages` is large (about 50 or larger), there will be an exception:

```
akka.stream.BufferOverflowException: Exceeded configured max-open-requests value of [32]. This means that the request queue of this pool (HostConnectionPoolSetup(api.bilibili.cn,80,ConnectionPoolSetup(ConnectionPoolSettings(4,0,5,32,1,30 seconds,ClientConnectionSettings(Some(User-Agent: akka-http/10.0.9),10 seconds,1 minute,512,None,<function0>,List(),ParserSettings(2048,16,64,64,8192,64,8388608,256,1048576,Strict,RFC6265,true,Full,Error,Map(If-Range -> 0, If-Modified-Since -> 0, If-Unmodified-Since -> 0, default -> 12, Content-MD5 -> 0, Date -> 0, If-Match -> 0, If-None-Match -> 0, User-Agent -> 32),false,akka.stream.impl.ConstantFun$$$Lambda$244/19208387@4780bf,akka.stream.impl.ConstantFun$$$Lambda$244/19208387@4780bf,akka.stream.impl.ConstantFun$$$Lambda$245/6903324@1d25a2e),None),TCPTransport),akka.http.scaladsl.HttpConnectionContext$@796a3e,akka.event.MarkerLoggingAdapter@1cc552a))) has completely filled up because the pool currently does not process requests fast enough to handle the incoming request load. Please retry the request later. See http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/scala/http/client-side/pool-overflow.html for more information.
```

How to solve it?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The thing you are looking for is dedicated [host connection pool](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/10.0.9/scala/http/client-side/host-level.html)
The simplified resulting code would be like this:

```
val poolClientFlow =
    Http().cachedHostConnectionPool[HttpRequest](host, port)

def performRequest(request: HttpRequest): Future[HttpResponse] =
    Source
      .single(request)
      .via(poolClientFlow)
      .mapAsync(1) {
        case (response, _) =>
          Future.fromTry(response)
      }
      .runWith(Sink.head)
```

Make sure you'll call

```
response.discardEntityBytes()
```

or just unmarshal it to prevent resource leak.

They warn in docs that it's an antipattern, but it actually runs well if you have enough memory and do not need any queue management.

Comment: This is what I wanted! But is `Source(requests)` (where `requests` is a `IndexedSeq[(HttpRequest, Int)]`) instead of `Source.single` is better?

Comment: It really depends on your needs. They would be queued through connection pool anyway even if you call `performRequest` from different threads.

Comment: No, that's actually not such a good idea. This might run into the same error and is less performant than your original code. See the notes in the documentation for more information.

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like

```
 val result = Source(1 to 10).mapAsyncUnordered(parallelism = 5) { count =>
    getCommentPage(av, count)
 }.runWith(Sink.seq)
```

Note that parallelism value should be less than `akka.http.host-connection-pool.max-connections`

Answer (score -2):

Why not go to the website in your error message?

http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/scala/http/client-side/pool-overflow.html

You need to configure your application.conf with `akka.http.host-connection-pool.max-connections` and increase the number from 32 to a much higher number.

Comment: I don't think changing the config is a good way to solve that. Too many HTTP connections at the same time are not good. Actually, I want to find a way like HTTP queue to solve that. Seems that `Flow` is a powerful way to solve it but I don't know how to use it. Even I change the `max-connections`, this should not be work because the `pages` might be very very large